# Karma Jasmine with observable, code coverage not fully coveraged

Tags: javascript, angular, observable, karma-jasmine

I try to do some unit tests for the ngOnInit and I am using jasmine/karma as unit test suit. And I hava a  that looks like this component:

```
  hasQuestionTree: boolean;

constructor(
    private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver,
    private authService: AuthService,
    private sidebarService: SidebarService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loginStatusSubscription = this.authService
      .loginStatus()
      .subscribe(user => {
        this.isLoggedIn = this.authService.isLoggedIn(user);
      });
    this.hasQuestionTree = this.sidebarService.sidebar;
    this.sidebarService
      .hasSidebar()
      .subscribe(hasSidebar => (this.hasQuestionTree = hasSidebar));
  }
```

And the sidebar service looks like this:

```
xport class SidebarService {
  private _sidebar = false;

  public sidebarObservable: Observable<boolean>;
  public sidebarSubject = new ReplaySubject<boolean>(1);

  constructor() {
    this.sidebarObservable = this.sidebarSubject.asObservable();
  }

  public get sidebar(): boolean {
    return this._sidebar;
  }

  public hasSidebar(): Observable<boolean> {
    // this.sidebarSubject.next(this.sidebar);
    return this.sidebarObservable;
  }

  public setSidebar(has: boolean) {
    this._sidebar = has;
    this.sidebarSubject.next(has);
  }
```

I have the unit tests like this:

```
describe('MainNavComponent', () => {
  let component: MainNavComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MainNavComponent>;
  const fakeSidebar = {
    sidebarState: of({ sidebar: false }),
  };

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [NoopAnimationsModule, AppModule],
      providers: [{ provide: AuthService, useClass: AuthMockService },
         { provide: SidebarService, useValue: fakeSidebar }]
    })
      .compileComponents()
      .then(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MainNavComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
      });
  }));

  it('should compile', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should isLoggedIn to true', () => {

    //Act
    component.login();
    // Assert
     expect(component.isLoggedIn).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should isLoggedOut to true', () => {
    //Act
    component.logout();

    //Assert
    expect(component.isLoggedIn).toBeFalsy();
    expect(component.logout).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('Should show the sidebar when hasQuestionTree is true', () => {
    expect(component.hasQuestionTree).toEqual(false);
  });


});
```

But this part:

```
hasSidebar => (this.hasQuestionTree = hasSidebar));
```

is still red in the code coverage.

SO my question is, how to test that part on a correct way?

Thank you.

oke, I have it now like this:

```
 const fakeSidebar = {
    hasSidebar: () => of({ sidebar: false }),
  };
```

and this:

```
  it('Should show the sidebar when hasQuestionTree is true', () => {
    expect(component.hasQuestionTree).toEqual(true);
  });
```

But I get this error:

```
MainNavComponent Should show the sidebar when hasQuestionTree is true
Expected Object({ sidebar: false }) to equal true.
```

Comment: You might want to edit your post and add the "this part" that's still red in the coverage report, because it doesn't seem to be there.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I edit iin the post

Comment: I suspect your test code completes before the `subscribe` callback executes.

Comment: What I have to improve then?

Comment: Use asynchronous test helpers, like `async` & `detectChanges`.

Comment: ?? but where? Don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be that I'm missing something but you are calling `hasSidebar()` on `this.sidebarService` which is provided with `fakeSidebar`, but this object actually doesn't define a `hasSidebar` method? For me it looks like your mock object should look something like this:

```
const fakeSidebar = {
    hasSidebar: () => of(true),
  };
```

Using the `of` operator also results in a synchronous observable so there should be no need for any `async` helper, but you might want to change that with using the `observeOn` operator and passing the `asyncScheduler` to simulate real world behavior?!

---

Updated this answer as well but I actually don't get the purpose of your test. You are just testing if a mocked method returns the value specified??

Comment: Yes, oke, but How to pass the component for 100% coverage? That was my question: this part hasSidebar => (this.hasQuestionTree = hasSidebar)); is red

Comment: when you are aiming for 100% test coverage then you need to use the snippet above. But 100% coverage is not always a worthwhile goal, but that's up to you to decide what needs to be tested and what not

Comment: Thank you anyway. for your effort.